# Expected Value and Most Likely Outcome

Tags: expected-value, mode

I was watching [this Khan video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqcxYnNlI3Y&index=34&list=PLC58778F28211FA19) on Expected Value as a refresher.
He mentions in passing that

> the expected value is the most likely outcome...

Well, that's only true because he's using a binomial distribution as his example, right?

Comment: For a balanced die, the expectation is 3.5, which is not even a possible outcome.

Comment: The most likely value of a distribution is called the mode, which is indeed distinct from the mean, a.k.a. the expected value.

Comment: Let me step back to take a look at the bigger picture. The Khan Academy video is bogus cr@p.

Answer (score 17):

It's not true in general that the expected value is the most likely outcome. Even for binomial distributions. For example, say we flip a fair coin 5 times. The number of heads has a binomial distribution with expected value 2.5. It's not even possible to obtain this outcome (similar to what Zen mentioned in the comments about rolling a die). Or, say we draw a value from a bimodal distribution like this:

[image]

The expected value is zero, but the probability density associated with this outcome is quite low.

Comment: is the most likely value(s) {-3,+3} ?